# Cypher: Is it possible to find creepy people following my friends?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I've pulled down the Twitter graph local to myself into Neo4J. I want to find people who follow my friends in number larger that should be expected. More specifically, I want to find people who follow the people I follow, but I want the results to be sorted so that the person following the highest number of my friends is sorted first. Possible in Cypher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a console example:

http://console.neo4j.org/r/p36cgj

```
create (me {n:"a"}), (fo1 {n:"fo1"}), (fo2 {n:"fo2"}), (fo3 {n:"fo3"}), (fr1 {n:"fr1"}),
(fr2 {n:"fr2"}), (fr3 {n:"fr3"}),
fo1-[:follows]->me, fo2-[:follows]->me, fo3-[:follows]->me, me-[:follows]->fr1, 
me-[:follows]->fr2, me-[:follows]->fr3, fo1-[:follows]->fr1, fo2-[:follows]->fr2, 
fo1-[:follows]->fr2, fo1-[:follows]->fr3;


start me=node:node_auto_index(n="me") 
match me-[:follows]->friends<-[:follows]-follower-[:follows]->me 
return follower, count(friends) as creepinessFactor, length(me-[:follows]->()) as countIFollow 
order by creepinessFactor desc;
```

I'm curious to hear the results, btw. :P

You could also throw in a `where` like:

```
where not(me-[:follows]->follower)
```

To avoid getting friends within your circle.