# Neo4j Sort by whom I follow, who follows me, others

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's suppose a social network

Code at ne4j console: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=fij8qs

```
CREATE (p1:PERSON {name: "Edson"})
CREATE (p2:PERSON {name: "Clades"})
CREATE (I:PERSON {name: "Mateus"})
CREATE (other:PERSON {name: "Goku"})

CREATE (alb:ALBUM {name: "Férias"})

CREATE I-[:HAVE_ALBUM]->alb
CREATE I-[:FOLLOW]->p1

CREATE p1-[:LIKE]->alb
CREATE p2-[:LIKE]->alb
CREATE other-[:LIKE]->alb
```

**HOW**:
select all people who **likes** the album. 
**order by** my friends **after** by friends of my friends, **then** by any other.

Select all that [:LIKE] my album ORDER BY

```
I-[:FOLLOW]
p2-[:FOLLOW]->person-[:LIKE]->alb // friend of my friend
person-[:LIKE]->alb //other
```

similar question
[[Cypher: Is it possible to find creepy people following my friends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688263/cypher-is-it-possible-to-find-creepy-people-following-my-friends][1])

Comment: the console link did not work, I've recreated the console at http://console.neo4j.org/r/gnjjka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an optional match with variable length to know the distance between you and the likers of the album and then sort by distance:

```
MATCH (person)-[:LIKE]->(:ALBUM {name:"Férias"}), (me:PERSON {name:"Mateus"})
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(me)-[:FOLLOW*]->(person)
WITH person, coalesce(length(p), 9999) AS distance
RETURN person, distance
ORDER BY distance
```

The `coalesce` assigns a high value of 9999 to everyone you don't follow directly or indirectly.

Comment: I just change * to *..2
Why if I put [:FOLLOW*]  It return repeated data?

MATCH (person)-[:LIKE]->(:ALBUM {name:"Férias"}), (me:PERSON {name:"Mateus"})
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(me)-[:FOLLOW*..2]->(person)
WITH person, coalesce(length(p), 9999) AS distance
RETURN person, distance
ORDER BY distance